# slideToggle container along with button innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I code a button that slideToggle container when clicked:

```
<a href="#" id="toggleButton">innerHTML</a>
<div id="toggleBody">Body Container</div>
```

Using jQuery slideToggle call function:

```
$('#toggleBody').hide();
$('#toggleButton').click(function() {
    $('#toggleBody').slideToggle(200);
});
```

Which I need to toggle the button innerHTML to something else along with toggled `toggleBody` container. Any help?

Code snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/9kyr76y1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.text()` callback function to get current text and toggle with new value:

```
$('#toggleButton').click(function() {
 $(this).text(function(i, text){
      return text === "innerHTML" ? "outerHTML":"innerHTML";
  })
 $('#toggleBody').slideToggle(200);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u3rwu5v2/)**

Comment: How to make the innerHTML accept HTML code like "<span class="class">open</span>"